# python array initialise doesn't work that i expected

Tags: python

```
 data=[ ]
 for i in range (1,size):
   in_size=len(b[i])
   for j in range (0,in_size):
    data[i][j]=b[i][j]
```

An array `data0[ ]` declare and try to assign values using loops but in the assignment statement it shows errors
shows:

```
error: str object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: What is `b`; why are you iterating from `1 to size`?

Comment: Sorry, it's very difficult to understand exactly what you're asking. What is `b`? it looks like you're trying to index `data` as though it was a nested list, but in your example it's an empty list.

Comment: So unreadable , I dont even know what You want to do. Pls Try another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be improved a lot but I am just making the least changes to make it work so that you understand the error:

```
 data=[ ]
 for i in range (1,size):
   in_size=len(b[i])
   temp_li = []
   for j in range (0,in_size):
     temp_li.append(b[i][j])
   data.append(temp_li)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're a little off on your syntax.

```
data = []
for i in range(1, size):
     in_size = len(b[i])
     for j in range(0, in_size):
         data.append(b[i][j])
```

Comment: unable to append values to a particular index eg: a[0].append(str)

Comment: You can't append values to a particular index. That operation is called insert.